# average of rating on condition basis | mongoose agregrate

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to $project the Recipe collections, where feedBack is my array of objects through which I have to lookup data from user collection to get the user name only if the isDelete value of feedback array of objects is false. If all the condition meets, then I want to add a averageRating field which is calculating the average of my feedBack.

My Recipe document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("61404f0023d34b53c8982d47"),
    "feedBack" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("615161de8bf6f93620bb41b0"),
            "review" : "good",
            "rating" : 2,
            "userId" : "884096bf-0a8f-4d89-bcbb-4bbf70fb0198",
            "time" : ISODate("2021-09-27T06:17:02.115Z"),
            "id" : "e6ed5d23-0bef-41c9-86e7-c7ecdd015aca",
            "isDelete" : true
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("615161e78bf6f93620bb41b4"),
            "review" : "good",
            "rating" : 4,
            "userId" : "9bc033b8-0592-40e4-8080-21e0038aac12",
            "time" : ISODate("2021-09-27T06:17:11.085Z"),
            "id" : "514367e4-1155-4075-a58e-84a158e52288",
            "isDelete" : false
        }
    ]
}
```

My User document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("61389fa03ac2c73724b4ed8b"),
    "accountType" : "email",
    "name" : "daniyal",
    "id" : "9bc033b8-0592-40e4-8080-21e0038aac12",
  
}
```

My desire output:

```
feedbackDetails: [ {
                                "id": "514367e4-1155-4075-a58e-84a158e52288",
                                "time": "2021-09-27T06:17:11.085Z",
                                "rating": 4,
                                "review": "good",
                                "userName": "daniyal",
                                "isDelete": false
                            } ]

averageRating: 4.5
```

feedBack details array should check the feedback document isDelete value. If it is false then it will calculate the average of all the documents rating value.

My code :

```
 "feedBackDetails":
                {
                    "$map": {
                        "input": { "$zip": { "inputs": ["$feedBack.id", "$feedBack.time", "$feedBack.rating", "$feedBack.review", "$userRole.name", "$feedBack.isDelete"] } },
                        "as": "el",
                        "in": {
                            "id": { "$arrayElemAt": ["$$el", 0] },
                            "time": { "$arrayElemAt": ["$$el", 1] },
                            "rating": { "$arrayElemAt": ["$$el", 2] },
                            "review": { "$arrayElemAt": ["$$el", 3] },
                            "userName": { "$arrayElemAt": ["$$el", 4] },
                            "isDelete": { "$arrayElemAt": ["$$el", 5] }
                        }

                    }
                },
```

Comment: Why is `averageRating` 4.5? Which values are you using? Also I have [this example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/1zyTs91R3ln).

Comment: Have you tried using $filter with $project to select only the desired array elements?

Comment: J.F in my case calculate avg feedback only if feedback isDelete value is false

Comment: Joe this case $filter didn`t work because if I add filter it will take multiple object record